# Определить количество чисел в наиболее длинной последовательности из нулей

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо:

Определить количество чисел в наиболее длинной последовательности из нулей, идущих подряд (в серии нулей). Результат вывести на экран.

Код:

```
import random

a = []
for i in range(100):
    n = int(random.random() * 2)
    a.append(n)
    print(n, end=' ')
    if (i + 1) % 10 == 0:
        print()
```

Comment: что такое серия нулей. Имеете ввиду нули, находящиеся у чисел на одном и том же разряде?

Comment: @Miron я так понял нули, идущие подряд.

Comment: @finally У одной строки / одного числа?

Comment: @Хлеб А в чем проблема то?

Comment: Конструкция `int(random.random()*2)` выглядит довольно странно. Почему бы не использовать `random.randint(0,1)`?

Comment: @Хлеб, не нужно делать правки, явно ухудшающие качество вопроса - даже если вы сами задали этот вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Найти максимальную последовательность `0` можно и без хранения в список чисел.

Делаем текущий счетчик последовательности и максимальный, и вызываем их проверку при встрече с значением, не равным ожидаемому, или если дошли до последнего числа (конца):

```
import random

cur_seqs = 0
max_seqs = 0
N = 100

for i in range(N):
    n = random.randint(0, 1)
    print(n, end='')

    if n == 0:
        cur_seqs += 1

    if n != 0 or i == N - 1:
        if cur_seqs > max_seqs:
            max_seqs = cur_seqs

        cur_seqs = 0

print()
print(max_seqs)
```

---

Найти наибольшую последовательность можно через `groupby`. Эта функция группирует подряд идущие элементы:

```
from itertools import groupby
import random

nums = []
for i in range(100):
    n = random.randint(0, 1)
    nums.append(n)
    print(n, end='')

print()

max_seqs = max(
    len(list(seqs)) for n, seqs in groupby(nums) if n == 0
)
print(max_seqs)
```

Например для: *10010100001110100010001**000000**11000111001011011**000000**100100001000100111001010110101111001010010111111*

Результатом будет: `6`

Работает это так:

- `for n, seqs in groupby(nums)` вернет кортеж вида (`<число последовательности>`, `<генератор последовательности>`)
- `len(list(seqs)) for n, seqs in groupby(nums) if n == 0` -- оставляем только последовательности из `0`, приводим генератор к списку и получаем количество элементов
- `max(...)` -- переберет все элементы и оставит максимальный, т.е. останется максимальная длина

Answer (score 2):

как вариант

```
import re


seq = '1001010000111010001000100000011000111001011011000000100100001000100111001010110101111001010010111111'


r = re.findall(r'0{1,}', seq)
print(len(max(r)))
```

Comment: r'0{1,}' можно заменить на r'0+' . Скрость работы правда будет низковатой.

Comment: у меня timeit на 10000 итераций показывает на r'0{1,}' 0.22919453422508695
а на r'0+' 0.23411949182377612

Comment: точно - все верно тем боле +, синоним {1,} - только вспомнил.